# How do I use fseek() to move the pointer in a fread() function properly? (C)

Tags: c, pointers, bmp

I'm trying to use the `fseek()` function to move a pointer to `fread()` to make `fread()` take data and pass it to `fwrite()` n number of times. Specifically, I need to enlarge a bmp by a scale of n.

So to do the vertical enlargement, I'm attempting to move the `fread()` pointer back by the width of the input BMP using `fseek()`.

The input and output data are both 24bit BMPs.

```
fseek(inputPointer, lineBytes, SEEK_CUR);
```

To calculate the offset, I used sizeof(pixel) * width of BMP * -1.

My two main questions are as follows:

1. How do I check the current position of a pointer in a line of code?
2. Does `fread()` actually move the pointer passed through it or just reads everything from the pointer to end of file?

Comment: 2. Question: `fread` reads as many bytes as you are asking for from the current pointer which is zero after opening the file and which you can set with `fseek`. Example: your file contains `123456789`, you read 4 bytes you get `1234`, you read another 3 bytes right after and you'll get `567`, then you `fseek` to position 2, you read 2 bytes and you'll get `34`.

Comment: 1. Question: you are looking for [`fgetpos`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgetpos/)

Comment: Hint. before trying to do bmp manipulations as you are describing, get familiar with the `fopen`, `fread`, `fwrite`, `fseek` and `fgetpos` by making some simple test programs.

Comment: Thank you, that really makes a lot more sense now. In regards to fread is the data that you read each time stored in the location of a pointer that can then be accessed by fwrite ?

Comment: Yes, if the file is opened in read/write mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. How do I check the current position of a pointer in a line of code?

From the context of your question, I think you're asking how to find the current position of a stream.  That would be the purpose of `ftell()` or `fgetpos()`.  The former is the one more conventionally paired with `fseek()`:

```
long offset = ftell(my_file);
```

> 2. Does fread() actually move the pointer passed through it or just reads everything from the pointer to end of file?

Using the more conventional term "offset" instead of "pointer" may help you.  In any case, the current file offset describes how many bytes past the beginning of the file is the next byte that will be read or written.  So if the offset is 0 then the next byte read will be the first in the file; if the offset is 16 then the next byte read will be the 17<sup>th</sup> (skipping or having already read the first 16).  `fread()` may or may not read all the way to the end of the file from there, depending on its arguments and the length of the file.

> I'm attempting to move the fread() pointer back by the width of the input BMP [...]
>   To calculate the offset, I used `sizeof(pixel) * width of BMP * -1`.

Based on your code, I suppose you mean that you want to move the file offset by the width of the BMP *measured in pixels*, for otherwise multiplying by `sizeof(pixel)` does not make any sense.  Even so, that may not be the right factor.  `sizeof(pixel)` measures the size of *the program's* representation of `pixel` (whatever that is), which might well differ from the size occupied *in the file* by one pixel.  If they do differ, then the latter is the one you want.

Additionally, if you want to change the offset forward or backward by one row, then the `-1` makes no sense to me whatever.  (Regardless of the specific significance of individual file offset values you ask about in your (2), as that disappears when you compute a difference between two offsets).